# Flash drive suddenly died. Why? Can I recover it?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, hard-drive

I have a flash drive that I used not too much but, after few month of inactivity, it died. I know that flash drives have a limited write cycles but I am sure that this is not the problem.

I tried to create a new partition table and format the drive nothing worked. This is the output of mkfs.ext2.

```
marco@pinguina:~$ sudo LANG=en.UTF-8 mkfs.ext2 -v -c /dev/sdc1 
[sudo] password for marco: 
mke2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
fs_types for mke2fs.conf resolution: 'ext2', 'default'
Calling BLKDISCARD from 0 to 4001431552 failed.
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
244320 inodes, 976912 blocks
48845 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=1002438656
30 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8144 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Running command: badblocks -b 4096 -X -s /dev/sdc1 976911
badblocks: Input/output error during ext2fs_sync_device
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                
Block 0 in primary superblock/group descriptor area bad.
Blocks 0 through 2 must be good in order to build a filesystem.
Aborting....
```

Is there something I can do to recover it?

Comment: Recover the Data or recover it for continued use?

Comment: @Moab: I wanna recover my drive as I like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the drive died definitely. I can not format it with any tool I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if it has a backup super block that you can use to repair it.

There is a [good article here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/) that could give you some ideas (It's on ext3, not sure if it will work on ext2).

Try this to see if you have a chance of it working:

```
$ dumpe2fs /dev/sdc1 | grep superblock
```

Comment: Thank you Dan but I tried ext2 because maybe linux tools handle better this filesystem type but originally the partition was formatted as fat32